# Unattended upgrades config has a line enabled by default. What is it for?

Tags: debian, apt, unattended-upgrades

I enable the following line in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` according to the [standard Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)

```
"o=Debian,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security";
```

to get security updates automatically.

Now I noticed that the line

```
"origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
```

is enabled by default. What is this for? I'm worried because this comes right after the lines with "stable" code-name, which might get my Jessie to upgrade to Stretch in the background. So what does this line do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line enables unattended security updates for the currently installed release. As indicated in the comment at the start of the file,

```
// Within lines unattended-upgrades allows 2 macros whose values are
// derived from /etc/debian_version:
//   ${distro_id}            Installed origin.
//   ${distro_codename}      Installed codename (eg, "jessie")
```

So the line you added is redundant. The codename won't be interpreted as "stable", so you won't upgrade to Stretch automatically.

Comment: What's the difference between that and what I enabled manually?

Comment: Nothing now, but with the `${distro_codename}` variant you won't need to change your configuration when you upgrade to another release.

Comment: So it's a duplicate? If I don't enable that line I enabled, it'll still do security updates?

Comment: Yes, security updates are enabled by default.